# What is the shortest way to apply "Yoda conditions" in C with VIM

Tags: vim

Using VIM, what is the fastest way to swap words around `==` ?

Example:    `x.y.z == 78` after reshuffle should become `78 == x.y.z`

Comment: depends on how many times you have to do it, with or without regex? or is it like a vimgolf question? Are you looking for the least keypresses?

Comment: It'd be pretty difficult (=impossible) to do this robustly for arbitrary expressions without actually parsing C.

Comment: @Doktor OSwaldo, it's about keypresses.

Comment: Then it is not suitable for SO, people here will give you good answers and not short ones. try asking on [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vim)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your cursor is at `x`, and there are other texts before and after this expression, like `foo bar x.y.z == 78 foo bar`

### without plugin

```
dE2Evbp3BP
```

You can press those keystrokes step by step to see what is going on.

### with plugin

This is typical use case for exchange plugin. ( 'tommcdo/vim-exchange')
Please read the doc of plugin for "how to use". With this plugin, we can:

```
cxE2Wcxe
```

Comment: Or shorter: `cxEW2W.`

Comment: In the "without plugin" there is an issue in the 3B part. It seems that it should be ```dEEEvbpBBPa ``` (with space at the end, followed by ESC).

Comment: @ivand58 oops.. you are right, but it would be better if it is `dE2Evbp2F<space>P`

Comment: @Kent, what is the advantage of pressing ```E2E``` instead of ```EEE``` (and ```2F``` / ```FF```) ?

Comment: @ivand58 `EE=2E` but `Fx;=2Fx`  do a `:h F` you will see. I said "better" in my above comment, because, I did the whole thing in normal mode. you add a `a`, to insert the blank perhaps, then you have to press `ESC` back to normal mode.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following substitution:

```
%s/\v(%(\w|\.)+)\s*\=\=\s*(%(\w|\.)+)/\2 == \1/gc
```

Sample input:

```
if (x.y.z == 78 && a.b.c == 55)
```

after substitution:

```
if (78 == x.y.z && 55 == a.b.c)
```

Or to handle `==` as well as `!=` comparisons:

```
%s/\v(%(\w|\.)+)\s*(!\=|\=\=)\s*(%(\w|\.)+)/\3 \2 \1/gc
```

Comment: This one is good for refactoring but it is longer than retyping the whole expression itself ... I will add it in my VIMRC , hanks.

Comment: How this expression can be extended to find both  ```==``` or ```!=``` ?

Comment: Something is wrong ```E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &```

Answer (score 0):

With regex (untested)

```
:%s/\(\S.\{-}\)\(\s*\)==\(\s*\)\(.*\)/\4\2==\3\1/
```